# Get value of a property in a component in a class dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection

I have the following class

```
public class Statement
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public Narrative Narrative { get; set; }
}

public class Narrative
{
    public string Narrative1 { get; set; }
    public string Narrative2 { get; set; }
    public string Narrative3 { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the Narrative1 property dynamically. Can anyone help how to achieve this?

I know how to get the value of a property name of a in a class using reflection.And here is the code for the same.

```
public static object ReflectPropertyValue(object source, string property)
{
    return source.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(source,null);
}
```

Can anyone help how to get the value of a property inside another property?

Thanks

Comment: Call `ReflectPropertyValue` twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's supose you have a `Statement` object, you could use the property `Narrative` property as `source` in your method. For sample:

```
var statement = new Statement();
// fill properties... change object's state

// get the reference of narrative object
object narrative = ReflectPropertyValue(statement, "Narrative");

// get the value and safe cast it to string
var narrative1Value = ReflectPropertyValue(narrative, "Narrative1") as string;
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Is there anyway we can flatten all the propeties?:)

Comment: No, It is recommended to use the properties one by one, like the sample :)